# Java 2D Help improve scrolling image; remove tearing(?) make smooter etc

Tags: java, game-development

I am a hobbyist attempting to implement some classics in Java 2D. I have problems getting some background images to scroll properly. Main problem seems to be the occurence of what I believe is called Tearing, ie old parts of "frames" are displayed giving a flickering effect in some parts of the image. Google tells me that it is probably related to missing VSYNC in windowed Java applications, and that it is impossible/very difficult to fix completely. However before giving up I thought to try asking here.

I have assembeled the code below as a bare bone example to illustrate the problem.

Any help of improving this code to reduce the Tearing/flickering would be much appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ScrollTest {
    
    private static int WIDTH = 320, HEIGHT = 240;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl","True"); //Does not seem to make any difference
        new ScrollTest().run(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 4, 1, "ScrollTest");
    }
    
    private boolean isRunning;
        
    protected JFrame window;
    protected Canvas canvas;
    private BufferStrategy bs;
    
    private int FPS = 100;
    private long targetTime = 1000 / FPS;
    
    protected int width;
    protected int height;
    protected float scale;
    protected float aspect;
    
    protected String title;
    
    protected BufferedImage screenImage;
    
    private BufferedImage bgImage;
    private int bgTop;
    private float offsetX;
    
    public void run(int width, int height, float scale, float aspect, String title) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.scale = scale;
        this.aspect = aspect;
        this.title = title;
        isRunning = false;
        try {
            init();
            isRunning = true;
            gameLoop();
        }
        finally {
            lazilyExit();
        }
    }
    
    public void init() {
        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)(width*scale), (int)(height*scale*aspect)));

        window = new JFrame();
        window.getContentPane().add(canvas);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setTitle(title);
        window.pack();
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        window.setVisible(true);
        
        canvas.createBufferStrategy(3);
        bs = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
        
        screenImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        
        //bgImage = loadBImage("res/res_DoubleDragon/Area 1_C_crop.png");
        try {
            bgImage = toCompatibleImage(ImageIO.read(new URL("https://spritedatabase.net/files/arcade/603/Background/Area1.png")));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
            
        bgTop = HEIGHT-bgImage.getHeight(null)+20;
    }
    
    public BufferedImage loadBImage(String filename)
    {
        try {
            return toCompatibleImage(ImageIO.read(new File(filename)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Image file not found");
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    public void gameLoop() {

        long timestamp;
        long usedTime;
        long sleepTime;
        long elapsedTime=0;
        
        while (isRunning)
        {
            timestamp = System.nanoTime();
            
            update(elapsedTime);
            System.out.println(elapsedTime);
            
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)screenImage.getGraphics();
            draw(g);
            g.dispose();
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
            g2.scale(scale,scale*aspect);
            g2.drawImage(screenImage,0,0,null);
            bs.show();
            g2.dispose();
            
            usedTime = System.nanoTime() - timestamp;
            
            sleepTime = targetTime - usedTime / 1000000;
            if(sleepTime < 0) sleepTime = 5;

            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            elapsedTime=(System.nanoTime()-timestamp) / 1000000;
            
        }
    }

    public void update(long elapsedTime) {
        offsetX -= .05f*elapsedTime;
        offsetX = Math.min(offsetX, 0);
        offsetX = Math.max(offsetX, WIDTH - bgImage.getWidth(null));
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        
        g.drawImage(bgImage, Math.round(offsetX), bgTop, null);
    }

    public void stop() {
        isRunning = false;
    }
    
    /**
        Exits the VM from a daemon thread. The daemon thread waits
        2 seconds then calls System.exit(0). Since the VM should
        exit when only daemon threads are running, this makes sure
        System.exit(0) is only called if neccesary. It's neccesary
        if the Java Sound system is running.
    */
    public void lazilyExit() {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                // first, wait for the VM exit on its own.
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
                // system is still running, so force an exit
                System.exit(0);
            }
        };
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }
    
    private static final GraphicsConfiguration GFX_CONFIG = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();

    public static BufferedImage toCompatibleImage(BufferedImage image) {
        /*
         * if image is already compatible and optimized for current system settings, simply return it
         */
        if (image.getColorModel().equals(GFX_CONFIG.getColorModel())) {
            return image;
        }
        System.out.println("incompatible image");
        // image is not optimized, so create a new image that is
        final BufferedImage new_image = GFX_CONFIG.createCompatibleImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), image.getTransparency());

        // get the graphics context of the new image to draw the old image on
        final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) new_image.getGraphics();

        // actually draw the image and dispose of context no longer needed
        g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.dispose();

        // return the new optimized image
        return new_image;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You could try setting the rendering hints to focus on speed `RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_SPEED` to see if it makes a difference for you: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/quality.html Otherwise you'll need to lower your fps or scroll speed. Depending on the size of the image, the display size and the graphics device rendering this code, too high of a draw speed or fps may be a little too much for many devices.

Comment: You likely know already, but vsync in short is an effort to match the fps of the application with the refresh rate of the screen. If the FPS is not matched (or is not a clean factor of the screen refresh rate, for example, half the rate which will draw a frame every two refreshes) then you may experience tearing if the frame is being drawn mid refresh.

Comment: @sorifiend. Thanks for the input. I tried the rendering hints, but it did not make a difference.